# Refinement of the Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $(X,\mathcal {B},\mu)$ and $(X,\mathcal{B}'\mu')$ are measure spaces on the same set $X$, we say that the latter is a **refinement**  of the former if $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{B}'$ and $\mu'\downharpoonright_\mathcal{B}=\mu$.

Any measure space admits a refinement to a complete measure space via [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure), and the resulting measure space is the coarsest refinement of the original measure space to a complete measure space. This implies that *it is possible for a complete measure space to admit a further refinement*, and such an example can be found in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/926691).

Now the  Lebesgue measure space $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d),m_d)$ is complete; but unlike the above example above, many subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are Lebesgue measurable and I was wondering if it admits a further refinement. Does it?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I hope you get a good answer. Nonmeasurable sets generally require the axiom of choice and are not constructible from unions and intersections of intervals. I find it unlikely that an interesting refinement exists but I don't know.

Comment: Instead of "refinement", the more usual word for this would be an **extension** of Lebesgue measure.  I think there have been some relevant previous questions either here or on MathOverflow.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did some research by with the word "extension" and found out that my question was a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Extension of the Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets)